# SQL Query incorrect syntax error c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

I'm getting the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.

When I run the following query

```
string query = "Update Job Set Name = @Name, Date = @Date, Material = @Material, Instructions = @Instructions, Group = @Group, Time = @Time, Address = @Address Where Id = @Id";

DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)jobGrid.Items.GetItemAt(0);
string name = drv.Row[0].ToString();

int Id = getId(name);

using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    string date = drv.Row[1].ToString();
    string material = drv.Row[2].ToString();
    string details = drv.Row[3].ToString();
    string group = drv.Row[4].ToString();
    string time = drv.Row[5].ToString();
    string address = drv.Row[6].ToString();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material", material);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructions", details);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", group);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", time);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

All of those things exist in the database in that order except for Id which comes first. I run a similar update using a different table in the database and it works perfectly. I'm not sure what is wrong with "Group" that makes that error. The value that I insert into Group is a string which is specified by the table ass varchar(50). I am using Visual Studio WPF c#

I can add and delete things from this table perfectly fine, but updating causes this issue

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved keyword - you need to escape it.  `[Group]` in SQL Server `\`Group\`` in MySQL.

Comment: OH! Thank you, I would've never gotten that on my own

Comment: And since you are using pass through queries you might want to take a peek at this article. You are likely going to get some strange behavior with your values occasionally that will be challenging to debug. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: If you had less ambiguous column names this would be a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets for reserved keywords like Date,Group,Time etc

```
Update Job Set Name = @Name, [Date] = @Date, Material = @Material, Instructions = @Instructions, [Group] = @Group, [Time] = @Time, Address = @Address Where Id = @Id
```

check [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that's the issue with just jumping into something instead of learning it from the ground up; you miss little things like this.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use square brackets for reserved keywords
Try this: Update Job Set Name = @Name, [Date] = @Date, Material = @Material, Instructions = @Instructions, [Group] = @Group, [Time] = @Time, Address = @Address Where Id = @Id